# Changing the text in a GKTurnBasedMatch's 'your turn' and 'game over' notifications?

Tags: ios, notifications, game-center, gamekit, multiplayer

I'm implementing a turn based multiplayer game using GameKit and GKTurnBasedMatch.  When the game is over, players receive a 'game over' notification; when it is a player's turn, they receive a 'your turn' notification.  These notifications occur automatically by using GKTurnBasedMatch.

Is it possible to change the text or icon displayed by these notifications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can change the text by setting the `message` property before calling the any of the functions that end the turn:

To set a custom message:

```
myTurnBasedMatch.message = @"It's now your turn!"
```

To let Game Center choose the message:

```
myTurnBasedMatch.message = @"" // or = nil
```

Once you start setting the `message` yourself, you need to set it every time (otherwise the previous message will be used, even for different circumstances, like someone wins the match).